# Ordinal isomorphic to $n\times\omega,n\in\omega$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

What ordinal is order isomorphic to $n\times\omega$ with the lexicographic order? I was thinking it is $\omega$ but I can't make an order preserving bijection between them. If it isn't $\omega$, which ordinal is it?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks, you're completely correct.

Answer (score 0):

$ n \times \omega$ with the lexicographical order is just $\omega \times n$.

Indeed, for ordinals $\alpha, \beta$, the order "$<$" on $\alpha \times \beta$ is like the lexicographical order except that one puts the second position first :
$$(a, b) < (a', b') :\Longleftrightarrow (b, a) <_\textrm{Lex} (b', a') $$

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean by lexicographic order?  For $3 \times \omega$,
$$
0\;0\\
1\;0\\
2\;0\\
0\;1\\
1\;1\\
2\;1\\
0\;2\\
1\;2\\
2\;2\\
0\;3\\
1\;3\\
2\;3\\
\vdots
$$
and from that we see that the order-type is $\omega$.

But if you mean the other lexicographic order, then the order-type is $\omega+\omega+\omega = \omega \;3$.